# Ansible inventory, make ansible_host point to two private iP addresses

Tags: ansible

wanted to know what syntax there is for making ansible_host point to two different addresses

```
[my_service]
dev_my_service_01 ansible_host=10.10.10.10
```

or

```
dev_my_service_01 ansible_host=10.10.10.10 20.20.20.20
```

or

```
dev_my_service_01 ansible_host=10.10.10.10/20.20.20.20
```

to make it hit either this or this address.

Comment: `what syntax there is for making ansible_host point to two different addresses` => none, this is not possible. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html. See definition for `ansible_host` and read the part concerning aliases.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is to conditionally define `dev_my_service_01`, which can be done in one of two ways:

- add two inventory entries, for `dev_my_service_01a` and `dev_my_service_01b`, and just accept that at least one play will fail
- or start out with only `localhost` in the play, then use [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/add_host_module.html) as localhost learns which of the two IPs is the "real" one, kind of like the snippet below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - command: ping -c 1 10.10.10.10
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: is_10
  - # etc etc
  - add_host:
     name: '{{ "10.10.10.10" if (is_10 is success) else "20.20.20.20" }}'
     groups:
     - my_service
- hosts: my_service
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: hello from the discovered host {{ ansible_host }}
```